# Error: Variable is read only . React Native Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, slider

I am trying to create backgroundcarousel for my app. i am getting

> 'DEVICE_WIDTH' is read only

when i remove it and add some value it has no error, but does not work as intended.

```
const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;

componentDidMount = () =>{
    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(
            prev => ({ selectedIndex: prev.selectedIndex === this.props.images.length - 1 ? 0 : prev.selectedIndex + 1 }),
            () => {
                this.scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
                    animated: true,
                    y: 0,
                    x: DEVICE_WIDTH = this.state.selectedIndex  //error here
                });
            }
        );
    },2000);
}
```

Comment: You can’t reassign a constant. Consider changing it to a let?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are trying to reassign a value to the DEVICE_WIDTH which is a constant.
Try declaring it as a var or let.